# How to execute bash file using RunShellScript in azure library for .Net

Tags: c#, bash, azure

I have a `bash` file with 50 lines of command that needs to be executed on Azure Linux VM. I am using azure library `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute` for .Net and found `IVirtualMachine.RunShellScript(List<string> commandLines, List<RunCommandInputParameter>)`. But it seems the method accepts only list of string commands. I understand I can split the bash file commands into multiple strings, but is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: why not pass a command that executes the bash file? If the bash file is on the VM.

Comment: @jegtugado my initial implementation was to deploy the script to VM, but automating the  process of deploying the script on VM wasn't really simple as in if we do `scp` we need an admin id/psw (not looking for an interactive way), and `customscripts` is slighly complex like having storage account and all that. I was wondering if I could pass `--scriptpath` as used in azure cli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run the bash scripts on Azure Linux VM, you have two choices: [Run Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command) and [Custom Script extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux). According to the situation, you can use custom script extension

For example

1. upload the bash file to Azure blob
2. Create a service principal and assign a role to sp

```
az login
az account set --subscription "<your subscription id>"
# the sp will have Azure Contributor role
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "readMetric"
```

[image]

3. Code

```
# use msal get token
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(<sp app id>)
           .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "<sp tenantID>")
           .WithClientSecret(<sp password>)
           .Build();
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" };
var  result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                   .ExecuteAsync();
TokenCredentials tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken,"Bearer");


    var client = new ComputeManagementClient(tokenCredentials);
    client .SubscriptionId = "<>";
            var resourceGroupName = "";
            var vmName = "";
            var extensionName = "";
            VirtualMachineExtensionInner para = new VirtualMachineExtensionInner { 
               AutoUpgradeMinorVersion=true,
               Location="",
               TypeHandlerVersion="2.1",
               VirtualMachineExtensionType= "CustomScript",
                Publisher = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
                Settings = new {
                    FileUris = new List<string>
                        {
                            "Azure blob url"
                        }

                },
                ProtectedSettings = new {

                    CommandToExecute = $"sh <bash file name>",
                    StorageAccountName = "<AccountName>",
                    StorageAccountKey = "<account key>"
                }
            };

            var result =await client.VirtualMachineExtensions.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, vmName, extensionName, para);
            Console.WriteLine(result.Id);
```